# Faster way than `C-u C-c C-l` to create an org link to a file opened in another buffer

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

Suppose I am am writing an org file `/path/to/foo/bar/notes.org` and I have in another window opened at the same time another file say `/path2/to2/foo2/bar2/file.tex` (living on a totally different path in the filesystem). Now I want to insert a link to `file.tex` into my org file. To do so, I would use `C-u C-c C-l` and then then navigate from `/path/to/foo/bar/` to the file to insert the link.

Is there a faster way to insert the link which uses the fact, that the file `file.tex` is already opened in another window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `org-store-link` by `C-c l` in `file.tex` buffer will store a link in the `org-stored-links` variable.

Then, calling `org-insert-link` by `C-c C-l` in `notes.org` buffer will insert the link to your org file by selecting the right stored link in the prompt.